# Utilizing WordPress's permalink structure on custom post types

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-post-type

I need to rewrite some URLs to custom templates. For example, I have a page at `domain.com/page`, and when a user clicks 'remove' on an element, it goes to `domain.com/page/?remove=54`. I'd like it to rewrite to `domain.com/page/remove/54`.

Help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: You might consider asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Very good point, I'm on it.. also, simplified the question quite a bit above. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact code is untested, but it's derived from another instance of a similar situation that I did solve recently:

```
add_action( 'init', 'ss_permalinks' );
function ss_permalinks() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'page/remove/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=page&service=$matches[1]',
        'top'
);
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'ss_query_vars' );
function ss_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'removeid';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Re-save your permalink settings once after implementing. `page` is the slug of the page to point to when the user access this URL (`domain.com/page/remove/432`), and `$matches[1]` should be the number after `remove/` in the URL. This number is accessible by the variable specified later, `$query_vars[] = 'removeid';`/ $removeid on the target page's template will be the number in the URL, if specified.

Comment: this code is not working for me, tried to run as it is and also saved the .htaccess from settings, but to no luck!